# Android O (API 26) Preview Emulator doesn't start

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, android-virtual-device, android-8.0-oreo

I downloaded the Android Studio 3.0 Canary 1 preview and used the AVD manager to download the Android O x86 system image.  When I set up an AVD with the wizard, using the Pixel phone as the hardware. When I start the emulator, it just hangs on the boot screen forever.

Comment: Same for me, running emulator on Debian using command line SDK (not Studio). Android is "loading" forever. If I close emulator and start again, I gent password prompt, after that - "Decryption unsuccessful".

Comment: Same here, my emulator works for API 25 and older but API 26 image does not start. Only a black screen. I am using Android 2.3.3.

Comment: I have created bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69280972 . Looks like something with SELinux. Try to boot from terminal, like `emulator -verbose -show-kernel -avd <your-avd-name>` to see actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Make sure to create a new virtual device instead of editing an existing one.

Comment: Yup, I did that.  Brand new AVD, still won't boot

Answer (score 1):

My OS is Debian 9. I have the same problem for API 26, but I can launch the emulator with API 25 without a problem thanks to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42903352/6603006

If you have any problem with API 25 on AVD Manager, you can use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) application. It's fast and stable.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue, i did the following steps to fix it

1) Updated Haxm and emulator from the SDK manager to the latest version

2) Delete the existing AVD with android 26 and create a new one

3) Tried emulating a phone with a lower resolution (like nexus 4). Pixel and pixel XL have high resolutions and run very slowly, so unless you HAVE to use the pixel device, I would recommend a lower res device which will put less strain on your machine. When I tried running API 26 on an emulated pixel it took hours to boot up.

Answer (score 1):

Look at bellow page. it has explained with details:
https://www.andreszsogon.com/using-android-8-and-9-emulators-without-android-studio/

briefly I did these steps to solved the problem:

1. Update **Android SDK Emulator** to a higher version
2. install higher **System Image** (for API 26)
3. install or update **HXAM**
4. delete old AVD machines
5. create new AVD machine with this configuration: ( **RAM: 2048** , **VM Heap: 256** )

Answer (score 0):

1.Delete all existing AVDs.
2.Invalidate Caches and restart
3.Clean and rebuild project
4.Create new AVD.

And make sure you have the latest version of emulator and HAXM installed from SDk Manager.

hope this helps.