# Android virtual device is not working in linux machine

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, ubuntu

Android virtual device is not working in linux machine- It shows an error message Grant current user access to /dev/kvm. How do I give them access?

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow. What Linux distribution are you using? Maybe duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300811/android-studio-dev-kvm-device-permission-denied

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: Solved, work for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42728353/cannot-start-android-device-emulator-on-linux