# Android device emulator on linux connectivity issue

Tags: linux, windows, flutter

I decided recently to try Linux for mobile development, but the emulator does not have an Internet connection (everything is fine on Windows).
Tried changing resolv.config - it doesn't help (although I may be doing something wrong). For the Internet, I use a mobile hotspot via Galaxy s21.
My Linux distro is kubuntu. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Hi Please check this question correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42728353/cannot-start-android-device-emulator-on-linux/42903352

Comment: If you are reffering to NVidia driver problems -then no. I don't even have Nvidia GPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether it is Nvidia or another videocard, the problem is related so check please  but not working plese check this  **Start the emulator with the -gpu off switch**.
but notworking check All I had to do was to turn off WIFI and disable networking, and then the emulator started when I ran it

Comment: I already followed and answered. No, this is not the problem. And the problem will not be related either.